# Splash screen only shows after clean install

Tags: android, installation, splash-screen

I have made a splash screen with an Activity. I followed following example http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?t=815 and it works perfectly when installed. But that's where my problem starts. It only shows after an install. So When I kill my app, the Activity isn't loaded anymore, it directly loads my second Activity. I think it's a little weird, because I set the intent-filter in my manifestfile on the splash screen.

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

This is my manifestfile:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:theme="@style/MyLightTheme.NoShadow" android:debuggable="true"  android:name="android.app.Application" > 
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
    <activity android:name="FindJob" android:label="@string/FindJobTitel"></activity>
    <activity android:name="JobDetails" android:label="@string/MaatTitel" ></activity>
    .
    .
    .
    <activity android:name="Splash" android:configChanges="orientation" android:label="@string/Splash">    
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter></activity>
</application>
```

Splashscreencode:

```
private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGHT = 5000;
//private Drawable drawable;
private ProgressBar mProgress;
private int mProgressStatus = 0;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
     super.onCreate(icicle);          
     setContentView(R.layout.splash);         
     mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);         
     }


public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    //Log.i("START", "In on start");
    Thread splashThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           try {
              int waited = 0;
              while (mProgressStatus < 100) {
                 sleep(80);
                 //waited += 200;
                 mProgressStatus += 4;
                 mProgress.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
              }
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              // do nothing
           } finally {
              finish();
             Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
              startActivity(i);
           }
        }
     };
     splashThread.start();   
}
```

UPDATE: placing `android:noHistory="true"` in the mainActivity in ManifestFile solves the problem. HOWEVER. Each time I leave the app, it restarts all of it (splash screen, mainactivity and not last activity loaded). But it's better then before.

Comment: Are you sure that the app was killed completely? It wasn't running in the background?

Comment: I've killed with advanced task killer, so I assume it was completely killed

Comment: I've also tried putting the code from my splashscreen in `onStart` method, but it also didn't help.

Comment: Weird! I just used your code to add a splash screen to one of my apps and it works fine. The splash activity is displayed each time I restart. What does LogCat say when you restart your app?

Comment: Wow this is really weird! When I restart my phone, the screen is also shown... Maybe I use the Activity Lifecycle wrong?

Comment: If the problem occurs again, check LogCat to see which Intent is launched. Maybe also add some log statements to the splash to see if onCreate is executed or not

Comment: He only goes one time in the onCreate method from the splash screen. When app is killed, he automatically goes in onCreate from MainActivity